# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In attempting to deploy a Flask application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' is thrown.

After reading several stackoverflow posts and sifting through AWS docs this same error is being produced, despite application working on local machine.

I'm using AWS EB w/ Linux 2 running Python 3.8.5.

My project tree:

```
-Crypto
 -App
  -folders
  -__init__.py
 -application.py
 -requirements.txt
```

Within the **init**.py file

```
  from flask import Flask
  from App.core.views import core


  application =  Flask(__name__)

  application.register_blueprint(core)

  application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
```

Within application.py

```
  from App import application

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      application.run(debug = True)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the way i understand this, the application object is not in `App.core`. it's in `App`

Comment: Typo, my apologies, please see edit. @Paul H

Comment: I'm getting same error while deploying FastAPI app